# Converting real to string rounds input

Tags: spotfire

I need to perform some manipulations of real type values that requires them to be converted to strings first.

The issue is that Spotfire is rounding the real input to 2 decimal places when performing the conversion.

I am using Spotfire version 6.5. In the attached screenshot the real column is shown with 'general' formatting along with the string output.

I would expect string(-0.0793)='-0.0793', not '-0.08'

Can anyone suggest a solution or know what's going on here?

[image]

Comment: Very odd. May I ask what manipulation you are going to do?

Comment: It's a head scratcher…. I can’t believe I haven’t come up against this weirdness before! Some of the values are not reportable (but I need to have a record in the table for them)- If they fall within certain bounds, I need to return a message using other values in the table. The logic looks something like

`Case when [value]<[x] or [value]>[y] then concatenate([a],[b])
When ……
Else string([value]) End`

I’ve tried Cast([value] as string) and I get the same result.

Comment: odd for sure. i can't find anything on it

Comment: So out of sheer curiosity, I tried concatenate([value], ""), and it looks like it's giving the full string.  Granted, I'm in version 7, so I can't confirm on your end.
Either way, that is downright bizarre.

Comment: Hi Chelsea- that works!! Many, many thanks :)